# Is this Object Oriented JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am using the following JavaScript, which I believe is Object Oriented. Others disagree that this is Object Oriented.

```
window.onload = function () {
var myphotos;
var currentImage;
var totalImageCount;

function initSlideImages(){
    myphotos = new Array (
            "slide_image_1",
            "slide_image_2",
            "slide_image_3",
            "slide_image_4",
            "slide_image_5"
        );
    currentImage = 1;
    totalImageCount = myphotos.length;

}

initSlideImages(); // Initialise slideshow

function nextPhoto(){
    currentImage++;
    if (currentImage > totalImageCount) {
        currentImage = 1;
    }
    var theImage = document.getElementById("slide_image");
    if (theImage != null){
        theImage.src = "images/portfolio/" + theImage.id + "_" + currentImage + ".jpg";
    }
}

function previousPhoto(){
    currentImage--;
    if (currentImage == 0){
        currentImage = totalImageCount;
    }
    var theImage = document.getElementById("slide_image");
    if (theImage != null){
        theImage.src = "images/portfolio/" + theImage.id + "_" + currentImage + ".jpg";
    }
}

var slide_prev = document.getElementById("slide-prev");
if (slide_prev != null){
    slide_prev.onclick = function() {
        previousPhoto();
    }
}

var slide_next = document.getElementById("slide-next");
if (slide_next != null){
    slide_next.onclick = function() {
        nextPhoto();
    }
}
```

}

Would you agree this is Object Oriented JavaScript? I believe it is. There is Constructor functions (eg. initSlideImages) and literal notation objects (eg. myphotos, currentImage). "slide_prev" and "slide_next" are methods as far as I am aware from my understanding of OO JS.

Am I right, or do I need to revisit Object Oriented JavaScript 101?

Comment: I don't see anything object-related in the above, aside from use of in-built methods and properties.

Comment: Looks more procedural than object oriented.

Comment: It appears to be more along the lines of a [Module](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

Comment: There you go: [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: Nope. Your `initSlideImages` is *not* a constructor and `myphotos` and `currentImage` are *not* objects.

Comment: No, this is not Object-Oriented. None of your explanation matches up with what I'd consider OO, there is no Constructor, no Object Literal or even methods. Your example `slide_next` is a variable with an element as the value, this isn't a method at all. Calling a function doesn't mean OO.

Comment: @depa: `currentImage` is certainly not an object, but technically speaking `myphotos` is an array object.

Comment: @FelixKling True. I should have said object literal.

Answer (score 3):

This is a traditional JavaScript, no way related to OOJS. OOJS creates new objects and member functions. An example of OOJS would be:

```
function Person() { }
var person1 = new Person();
var person2 = new Person();
```

Or something like this:

```
var myObject = {  

};
```

And this is how you define the methods:

```
function myObject(){  
    this.iAm = 'an object';  
    this.whatAmI = function(){  
        alert('I am ' + this.iAm);  
    };  
};
```

Or, the literal version is like this:

```
var myObject = {  
    iAm : 'an object',  
    whatAmI : function(){  
        alert('I am ' + this.iAm);  
    }  
}
```

**References**

1. [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
2. [The Basics of Object-Oriented JavaScript](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/)

Answer (score 3):

> There is Constructor functions (eg. initSlideImages)

The function `initSlideImages` is not used as a constructor.

> and literal notation objects (eg. myphotos, currentImage).

Those are not literals in the sense I think you mean. They're just plain old global variables. And even if they were, that doesn't have much to do with OOP in JavaScript.

> "slide_prev" and "slide_next" are methods as far as I am aware from my understanding of OO JS.

Those are *not* methods.

> Am I right, or do I need to revisit Object Oriented JavaScript 101?

You're pretty far from right. None of the terminology in your post is used accurately. Yes, you should start over at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks more procedural than object oriented. Object oriented often implies encapsulation and inheritance. In object oriented JavaScript your code would typically look something like this:

```
// Constructor
function Slider(photos) {
  this.photos = photos;
  this._init();
}

// Methods
Slider.prototype._init = function() {
  // grab selectors, add events, initialization logic
};

Slider.prototype.count = function() {
  return this.photos.length;
};

Slider.prototype.next = function() {
  //...
};

Slider.prototype.prev = function() {
  //...
};

var photos = [
  "slide_image_1",
  "slide_image_2",
  "slide_image_3",
  "slide_image_4",
  "slide_image_5"
];
var slider = new Slider(photos);

slider.next(); // go to next slide
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not object oriented JS. 
There is no object instantiation using 'new' operator. There are no properties defined for a 'class like' constructor function.

Refactored object oriented code is as below:

```
function SlideImages(){
    this.myphotos = new Array (
            "slide_image_1",
            "slide_image_2",
            "slide_image_3",
            "slide_image_4",
            "slide_image_5"
        );
    this.currentImage = 1;
    this.totalImageCount = this.myphotos.length;

}

//Object creation
var slideImages = new SlideImages(); 

//accessing object properties
console.log(slideImages.currentImage) //output:1
```